# What's the right way to get Android Wear to refresh a media notification?

Tags: android, android-notifications, wear-os, android-wear-notification

I have an app that plays music; I have a Broadcast Receiver that properly handles the commands from Android wear like `KEYCODE_MEDIA_PLAY`, `KEYCODE_MEDIA_PAUSE`, and `KEYCODE_MEDIA_NEXT`.

Everything works, but there's one issue: when I hit Play on the Wear notification, the Intent is fired, the music plays, but the notification isn't updated to show a 'Pause' icon until I swipe down and back up again, forcing the notification to be "refreshed."  This issue does not occur on the phone.  Is there a way to prompt this "refresh" to occur while the notification is active on the screen?﻿

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that this behavior was actually a bug in Android Wear since it seems to have been fixed with the 5.0.2 update.

Comment: Could you please add references like a link to the change log which lists this bugfix or the issue in the AOSP issue tracker related to this bug? Thanks.

Comment: This was based on a personal observation; I've had this bug consistently on my Moto 360 for the past few months.  Today, my watch got the OTA for 5.0.2 and the issue no longer exists.  That's the only variable that changed.  I spent a few minutes on the general Android issue tracker and couldn't pinpoint an exact issue.  As far as I know, not all Android Wear issues are going to be on that tracker especially if they weren't reported publicly.